# Исключение nil их Хеша

Tags: ruby

есть такая штука

```
My_hash = { "1" => [{"Первый" => "Red"},["12","13"]], "2" => [{"Второй" => "Green"},["22","23"]],
"3" => [{"Третий" => "Blue"},["32","33"]], "4" => [{"Четвертый" => "Blue"}]}

My_hash.each do |mar|   
  puts mar[1][1]
end
```

Как сделать так, если у Ключа хеша нет элемента [1][1] - мы его игнорируем?

Comment: а что значит - "игнорируем"?

Comment: В данном коде - просто не выводим в puts

Comment: `if mar[1] and mar[1][1]` ?

Comment: Да, опечатка  mar[1]. Можно же его пронать fff = My_hash.delete_if{ |k, v| v[1].nil? } ? И удалить все лишнее, а потом использовать?Вроде работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

собственно вот:

```
My_hash.each do |mar|
  next unless mar[1] && mar[1][1]
  puts mar[1][1]
end
```

игнорим mar[1][1]

Comment: Круто, еще проще.Спасибо

Comment: Можно проверку с `&&` переписать через `&.`: `unless mar[1]&.[](1)`, но это ещё страшнее выглядит на мой взгляд о_о

Comment: На самом деле,все варианты супер, для меня, больше буду знать. Спасибо

Comment: А, совсем забыл, есть же ещё `dig` (с 2.3+): `mar.dig(1, 1)`.